# Is the implementation of an web API (such as EventTarget, DOM）embedded in the browser source code?

Tags: javascript, api, browser

Is the implementation of an web API (such as EventTarget, DOM）embedded in the browser source code?

If so, what does it look like? And is it separated from the JavaScript engine?

Without the help of web APIs, can we write async callback functions?

Any brief explanation is appreciated. I'm just trying to have a concept of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the implementation of an web API (such as EventTarget, DOM）embedded in the browser source code?

Where else?

> If so, what does it look like?

[EventTarget in Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:ui/events/event_target.h;l=25?q=EventTarget&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc), and [in Firefox](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/events/EventTarget.h),the DOM implementation is a bit harder to show as it is composed of **many** such scripts, but using the websites I linked to, you can easily navigate it.

> And is it separated from the JavaScript engine?

Yes. The JS engine in Chromium based browsers is [v8](https://v8.dev/docs), the one in Firefox is [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey), in Webkit it's [JavaScriptCore](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore). While all these JS engines have been developed for browsers, they can very well work in other environments too, for instance node.js which doesn't implement the DOM uses v8 as its JS engine, or MongoDB switched from v8 to SpiderMonkey in its version 3.2.

Remember that a browser has many other things to do than executing our little JS scripts, and the JS engine is only a small part of these big piece of software.

> Without the help of web APIs, can we write async callback functions?

Sure if you have something else that offers the same behavior as what an [event-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) does, you don't need **Web* APIs, once again, node.js has an event-loop even though it doesn't follow the Web standards and doesn't implement the Web APIs (with a few exceptions).

However, JS in itself only introduces asynchronicity through [Promises](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-objects).

Comment: I don't even have the words to thank you, sir. You have my deepest thanks.